# Android BreadCrumbs separator

Tags: android, breadcrumbs, separator

How can I change the native BreadCrumbs separator from `|` to `>` or to any other special character.

I tried all the xml properties of bread crumbs, but didn't find any solution.

Same is the case with bread crumbs title text color and background color.

Answer (score 0):

If you use theme

```
  <style name="Theme.HanselAndGretel.DefaultLight" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="hagDividerVertical">@drawable/arrow</item>
    <item name="hagSelectableItemBackground">@drawable/hag__background_light</item>
</style>
```

change arrow icon